# how to use place search in google map just for Special areas in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google map in my app and want to use search in it but the problem is that I want to get results just for a special area or just search in a city!

Here is my code:

```
final int PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

 AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                        .setCountry("IR")
                        .build();
                try {
                    Intent intent =
                            new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY)
                                    .setBoundsBias(new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(38.051183, 46.211586),
                                                new LatLng(38.132784, 46.392860)))
                                    .setFilter(typeFilter)
                                    .build(MainActivity.this);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);

                } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                    e.fillInStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: I believe you asked the same thing in another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43845866/restrict-autocomplete-results-by-setboundsbias