# PlaceAutocompleteFragment - Unable to restrict place

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to restrict address search on a particular small town.

I got the coordinates on findlatitudeandlogitude.com.

Got the southwest coordinate and the northeast.

This is my code:

```
    PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_fragment);

    autocompleteFragment.setBoundsBias(new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(-23.10026, -47.008953),
            new LatLng(-22.9595, -46.922092)));

    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
            Log.i("APP", "Place: " + place.getName() + "Lat: " + place.getLatLng() + " Address: " + place.getAddress());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.i("APP", "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });
```

It doesn't restrict at all, it shows me address from all over the world. Also, is there a way to get the city of the selected place? there's no place.getCity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restrict autocomplete results by setBoundsBias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43845866/restrict-autocomplete-results-by-setboundsbias)